# Balloon tooltip with close button - C#

Tags: c#, taskbar, popup-balloons

How do I create a ballon tool tip with a close button.

I can show a tooltip:

```
TaskbarIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000);
```

but I can't do the opposite:

```
TaskbarIcon.CloseBalloonTip();
```

Or even a way to show a close box on a Balloon Tip.

I saw this question posted on another site but with no (free) answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The other site's paid-for answers don't magically become visible if you scroll down the page a bit further, do they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to find a simple answer. Instead of using:

```
TaskbarIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000);
```

I could use the second form of this function:

```
TaskbarIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000,"Title","Message",ToolTipIcon.None);
```

This actually adds a close box to the balloon tip!

Comment: Actually, the difference is not which overload of ShowBalloonTip you call, but whether or not you provide a title. If the title is null or empty, the close button is not shown

Answer (score 1):

You might find this interesting:

http://www.tooltips.net/

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902642/how-to-hide-a-taskbar-balloon-at-will) has a helpful answer on closing the balloon.

Unless you need to hook an event on close, you don't need a button on the balloon, and even if you do, you can hook the balloon's click event to accomplish the same thing.

There are flags that allow you to do things like put an X in the upper right hand corner of the balloon so that the user can dismiss it.  See here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188923.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and the support).

I was kind of looking for a way outside of Win32 and Shell_NotifyIcon. Something in C# like NotifyIcon.

Comment: The ToolTip class in the .NET Framework should have everything you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx